# Ruby on rails devise user model can create a team and become leader or join an existing team as member

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, associations

Hey guys im working on a rails application where users that have successfully signed up and logged in to their dashboard can create a team and become the leader (invite others to join via email, delete existing members etc.) or join an existing team as a member.( can only view other members and information about themselves) I'm using the Devise gem for user login / sign up since it has a lot of what i need. A team has one manager and has many members. Heres what ive tried, users belong to teams, and teams have many users. Ive also tried the association, Users have one team and teams have many users but one manager. I'm very confused thanks again.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable 
   validates_presence_of :phone, :city, :state, :street, :zip, presence: true, on: :create
   belongs_to :team 
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "firstname"
    t.string "middlename"
    t.string "lastname"
    t.string "phone"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "street"
    t.string "zip"
    t.bigint "team_id"
    t.index ["team_id"], name: "index_users_on_team_id"
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end
```

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, class_name: "User"  
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
   devise_for :users, path: 'users' , controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", confirmations: 'users/confirmations', registrations: 'users/registrations' }
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service, you have to show that you at least have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: sorry im new here im going to upload my code now

Comment: Ive edited my code and included what ive tried @max